# Groovy method return value is changed

Tags: groovy

The following Groovy method returns `false` (even though both query results are `0`). I am clueless :(

```
boolean checkObjects() {
    Sql.withInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//${db_host}:${db_port}/${db_servicename}", "${db_username}", "${db_password}") { sql ->
        result1 = sql.firstRow('select count(status) as count from all_objects where status=\'INVALID\'')
        result2 = sql.firstRow('select count(status) as count from user_objects where status=\'INVALID\'')

        boolean output = ("${result1.count}".toString() == "0") && ("${result2.count}".toString() == "0")
        println output // prints true
        return output
    }
}

println checkObjects() // prints false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake when you use closure in groovy:
Output is the return for the closure but the return of your function is withInstance

Try to declare output outside the closure and return it as the result of the function

Comment: Thanks! Totally overlooked the closure!